# cv2.imread: checking if image is being read

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm writing an OpenCV program in python, and at some point I have something like

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
... 
img = cv2.imread("myImage.jpg")

# do stuff with image here
```

The problem is that I have to detect if the image file is being correctly read before continuing. `cv2.imread` returns `False` if not able to open the image, so I think of doing something like:

```
if (img):
   #continue doing stuff
```

What happens is that if the image is not opened (e.g. if the file does not exist) `img` is equal to `None` (as expected). However, when `imread` works, the condition, breaks:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

i.e. the returned `numpy.ndarray` cannot be used as a boolean. The problem seems to be that `imread` returns numpy.ndarray if success and `False` (boolean) otherwise.

My solution so far involves using the `type` of the returned value as follows:

```
if (type(img) is np.ndarray): 
     #do stuff with image
```

But I was wondering: isn't there a nicer solution, closer to the initial check `if(img): #do stuff` ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're sure that the value of `img` is `None` in your case, you can simply use `if not img is None`, or, equivalently, `if img is not None`. You don't need to check the type explicitly.

Note that `None` and `False` are **not** the same value. However, `bool(None)==False`, which is why `if None` fails.

The documentation for `imread`, both for OpenCV 2 and 3, states, however, that a empty matrix should be returned on error. You can check for that using `if img.size ==0`

Comment: do you know if trying to read a non existent image using imread throws a cv2.error or something similar?

Comment: @waspinator the documentation states that `If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix`

Comment: This raised this exception for me, since it was comparing `None` to a matrix: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. @ZdaR answer, to check `isfile("myImage.jpg"), has been a better choice for me.

Comment: Is there any evidence that `img.size == 0` is correct? All I can find (and observe) is that `imread()` returns `None` on OpenCV >= 3.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to write the contents as soon as the image file is being generated then you can use `os.path.isfile()` which return a `bool` value depending upon the presence of a file in the given directory.

```
import cv2 
import os.path

while not os.path.isfile("myImage.jpg"):
    #ignore if no such file is present.
    pass

img = cv2.imread("myImage.jpg", 0)

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", img)
```

You can also refer to [docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#display-image) for detailed implementation of each method and basic image operations.

Answer (score 4):

from documentation, we may use

```
retval  =   cv.haveImageReader (filename)
```

source https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

Comment: How to check the ``multi number of images``? For example I have two classes ``,i.e., A and B`` and A contains ``500`` and B contains ``502`` images. How can I check for ``empty images`` in this condition? @Zdar

Answer (score 1):

this catches any error on opening file ops

```
try:
    img = cv2.imread("myImage.jpg")
except:
      print("error message")
      exit()
```