# Converting OpenCV code snippet from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to convert this code to python.
can anyone help me?

```
    cv::Mat image;
while (image.empty()) 
{
    image = cv::imread("capture.jpg",1);
}
cv::imwrite("result.jpg",image);
`
```

Comment: Just checking, have you pasted your complete code?

Comment: Why use the `while`? Can't you just do `if`?

Comment: @IronManMark20 : Initially, there is no image, so i have to wait until the image come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python the `Mat` of C++ becomes a [numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) array and hence the image manipulation becomes as simple as accessing a multi dimensional array. However the methods name are same in both C++ and Python.

```
import cv2 #importing opencv module

img = cv2.imread("capture.jpg", 1) #Reading the whole image

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", img) # Creating a new image and copying the contents of img to it
```

**EDIT**: If you want to write the contents as soon as the image file is being generated then you can use `os.path.isfile()` which return a `bool` value depending upon the presence of a file in the given directory.

```
import cv2 
import os.path

while not os.path.isfile("capture.jpg"):
    #ignore if no such file is present.
    pass

img = cv2.imread("capture.jpg", 0)

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", img)
```

You can also refer to [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160419113634/http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org:80/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#display-image) for detailed implementation of each method and basic image operations.

Comment: there is no while loop in this code and i need the presence of the while loop in my coding

Comment: But why ? @AliDhouib why are you making it complex ? it will serve it's purpose, try running it. please explain me the context ?

Comment: I have to wait until the program receive an image, it comes from another process throw a server! so i have to repeat reading the image from the path until it becomes true. And after reading that image, i have another process in this same program.

Comment: can you help me? any idea?

Comment: I will point you to here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628325/cv2-imread-checking-if-image-is-being-read