# Can't display image when using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, macos, image, opencv, imshow

I'm trying to display an image on screen using OpenCV, but nothing happens - all I see is a black screen.

No error message is received.

I'm using Mac and I have a secondary screen connected. When I run the code, both are turned black for 10 seconds but the image is not displayed.
This is the code:

```
    while True:
        if not os.path.isfile(pic_name):
            print("Wrong path: ", pic_name)
            return

        image = cv2.imread(pic_name, 0)
        if image is not None:

            print(image)

            cv2.imshow('image', image)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1000)

            if k == 27:         # If escape was pressed exit
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

            break
    return pic_time
```

Also - when printing the image as nd-array, values are good:

```
[[  0   3   4 ... 239 220   3]
[  0   2   0 ... 238 219   3]
[  2   6   0 ... 237 218   2]
...
[  0  26 127 ... 175 173   2]
[  0  33 149 ... 169 168   3]
[  3  22 145 ... 167 163   2]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check if your image actually loaded.

Comment: @MarkSetchell What do you mean? How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23628409/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell still doesn't work:
`while True:

            if not os.path.isfile(pic_name):
                print("Wrong path: ", pic_name)
                return
            image = cv2.imread(pic_name, 0)
            if image is not None:
                print(image)
                cv2.imshow('image', image)
                k = cv2.waitKey(1000)
        return pic_time
`
image is not None but I still get a black screen
Also, when I print the image it has actual values:
`[[180 177 182 ... 205 204 204]
 [180 176 181 ... 207 207 208]
 [179 175 180 ... 205 205 205]...`

Comment: Ugh! Pease don't put code in comments - it is hard to read. Rather, click `edit` under your question and update it there. What does `sips` have to say about the image you are using? `sips -g all YourImage.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, fixed the edit and put the code in the question.
sips output:
`pixelWidth: 533
  pixelHeight: 400
  typeIdentifier: public.jpeg
  format: jpeg
  formatOptions: default
  dpiWidth: 72.000
  dpiHeight: 72.000
  samplesPerPixel: 3
  bitsPerSample: 8
  hasAlpha: no
  space: RGB`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Any idea?

Comment: No, I'm stuck too :-( How did you install it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell using anaconda.. and I'm using Mac