# Error while opening the image in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to start with basics of opencv with python but when i executed the below code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('bg.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But i am getting this error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\OpenCV Programs\OpenCV1.py", line 7, in <module>
   cv2.imshow('image',img)
error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-
static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 
&& size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Plz help me out thank you..!

Comment: Why is this tagged both python-3.x and python-2.7? Do you need code that runs in both?

Comment: i m trying on both cause its giving this error..do you have any solution??

Comment: why not simple search the web for the error message. you don't have to post a question on StackOverflow for that...

Comment: You may want to read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628325/cv2-imread-checking-if-image-is-being-read) as well. Things sometimes fail in the real world, you have to write your software to account for that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works, if there is an image called `bg.jpg` within the same directory where you are running the code.

Anyway, you could try to reference the full path to the image:

```
import os

img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'bg.jpg')
img = cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The image you attempt to load does not exist.

As you cannot display a non-existing image you get an error messsage for trying.

You'll most likely messed up the path. Maybe use an absolute path to the image.