# openv program with python

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm not able to read the image

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('instra.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


import cv2
img = cv2.imread('instra.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: you didn't specify a window size

Comment: Have you tried specifing the full path to your image, does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are unable to load the image. Check if your image exist in current directory and see this post: [cv2.imread: checking if image is being read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628325/cv2-imread-checking-if-image-is-being-read) to check if your image is loaded.