# read an image from google drive using python in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, show, display, imshow

I write this simple program to read an image stored in google drive, but I receive this response when I executed it :

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/drive/my-drive/1.png')
cv2_imshow(img)
```

After execution :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-d0027ef4e25a> in <module>()
----> 1 cv2_imshow(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     20       image.
     21   """
---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     24   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

Answer (score 0):

'Nonetype' means your image wasn't loaded properly. I guess your path to the file should start with `/content` as it usually does working with Google Drive:

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/my-drive/1.png')
```

You can also check the path in the left-panel file explorer via right mouse click (by copying the full path).

Comment: in fact it's not a problem of read because I try the two manner but it can't work correctely

Comment: @3loumm3arif, what does the [following checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628325/cv2-imread-checking-if-image-is-being-read) says? Was your image really been loaded?